# Encode to JSON objects in PHP

Tags: php, json

How to encode to JSON objects in php?

**Pofile.php**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$check_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj1=json_decode($check_json);
 $id= $_GET['uuid'];
 $prep= $mysqli->prepare("select name,contact,location,bloodgp from signup where uuid= ?");
 $prep->bind_param("s",$id);
 $prep->execute();
$result= $prep->get_result(); 
$obj= json_encode($result);
?>
```

I want to encode the results into json objects.Is this is correct?How do i pass this encoded object?

Comment: where do you want to pass it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is the use of `$check_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj1=json_decode($check_json);` in your current code?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm trying to access the `id` using json decode method , then i want to encode the `result`

Comment: @ParitoshMahale I'm using React native as front end and php as back end.I wan't to pass this encoded output to native